# How to create a test to ensure no retain-cycle?

Tags: objective-c, testing, automatic-ref-counting

In one of mine project I have a quite complex data model.
I need a way to ensure that no retain cycle are created by me or by others colleagues and i want to use an automated approach.

There is a way to ensure that all the "dealloc" method are called?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Static Analyzer (from menu : Product - Analyze or shorcut `Shift+CMD+B`). Or you create Unit Tests https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UnitTestYourApp/UnitTestYourApp.html and check objects retainCount.
Leak instrument may help too : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks , https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can test such things automatically. Things you can do:

1. **Have good coding standards and program architecture**
   Good architecture will prevent many retain cycles.
2. **Be careful when using `self` in blocks (know when to use `__weak id self`).**
3. **Run `Instruments` and inspect leaks while your application is running**

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this you need to design & program it yourself.

For example you could:

1. Define "connection" as a strong reference to an instance of a class in your data model.
2. Define a protocol which provides either a "connected to" count method and one to return a connection by index *or* provides a connections iterator.
3. Have each class in your data model implement this protocol.
4. Now given a reference to your data model these protocol methods provide you with the "graph" (the objects are the nodes, the connections the arcs). Implement a cycle checking algorithm.

Now run the test at appropriate places during development & testing to check for accidental introduction of cycles.

You *may* be able to implement this without a protocol by using the facilities of the runtime, you can certainly given an arbitrary instance discover its ivars and whether an ivar is an object reference. You might get stuck though determining whether the ivar is strong or weak. While much more general this may be harder to implement, but once done...

HTH